# How does recursion works under loop and multiple funct. calls?

Tags: recursion, permutation

Well, recursion is always troublesome for me.

Can anyone explain me how recursion works in this function of calculating permutations of given string.

```
void permute(char *a, int i, int n)
{
   int j;
   if (i == n)
     printf("%s\n", a);
   else
   {
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
       {
          swap((a+i), (a+j));
          permute(a, i+1, n);
          swap((a+i), (a+j)); //backtrack
       }
   }
}
```

How does recursion works when there are 2 recursion calls followed by a statement in between? I hope i am clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to read the code out in english;

The function generates the perumtations the string a starting with the i'th element and ending with the n't element.

If i and n are equal we are done, there is only one element and only one permutation.

Otherwise;

For each j between i and n, inclusive in both ends.:
-Swap the position of the i'th element and the j'th element.
-Generate all permutations that does not change to order of the first i elements.
-Swap the i'th and j'th element back again.

The fact that the recursive call is in a loop means that it will be performed several times. - One time for each potenial first character of the string.

What the above means in a concrete example is that the algorithm will for the string "1234" do;

First generate the string that starts with "1" and is followed by all permuations of "234", ie all permutations of "1234" that happens to start with "1".

Then generate all permutations that starts with "2".

Then all that starts with "3".

And finaly all permuations that starts with "4".

Since all permutations of "1234" will start with "1","2","3" or "4", this will generate all permuations of the string "1234".

Proving that this works can be done by induction and "is left as an exercise for the reader".